# combine results of query into on array

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a database query

```
 `$select_top = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `wp_top_voted` WHERE `todays_date`= CURDATE() ORDER BY `number_votes` DESC LIMIT 10"));`
```

and I want to put the results in an array so it looks like `$ids = array(49968, 49993, 34711);`
 
I've done `foreach($select_top as $select_top_one){
$ids = array($select_top_one->post_id);` but this prints the array as `Array ( [0] => 49968 ) Array ( [0] => 49993 ) Array ( [0] => 34711 )`
how do I put these results in the form `$ids = array(49968, 49993, 34711);`

Comment: use `$ids[] = $select_top_one->post_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$ids[] = $select_top_one->post_id`

```
foreach($select_top as $select_top_one){ 
    $ids[] = $select_top_one->post_id;
}
print_r( $ids );
```